# pickled object and loading it into a numpy array

Tags: python, networkx, pickle

I am trying to create a graph using numpy array from a pickled directed graph, but I came across the following error.

Code:

```
filename="GAWD.pkl"
with open("result/" + filename, 'wb') as handle:
    # pickle.dump(data2, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
    pickle.dump(data2, handle)


with open("GAWD/data/injected/rand_injected.pkl", 'rb') as handle:
    data = np.array([g[0] for g in pickle.load(handle)], dtype=object)


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 150, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 30, in main
    graphs = read_graphs(FLAGS.input_file)
  File "F:\GAWD\utils.py", line 28, in read_graphs
    data = np.array([g[0] for g in pickle.load(handle)], dtype=object)
  File "F:GAWD\utils.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    data = np.array([g[0] for g in pickle.load(handle)], dtype=object)
  File "F:\envs\venv2\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\graph.py", line 476, in __getitem__
    return self.adj[n]
  File "F:\envs\venv2\lib\site-packages\networkx\classes\coreviews.py", line 82, in __getitem__
    return AtlasView(self._atlas[name])
KeyError: 0
```

Thank you for taking time to go through this!

Comment: Could you add a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: as Rivers said, we need more context to be able to help you